# Get bounding box of color content

Tags: php

I have several jpgs like this:

[image]

I need to have a way to use PHP to detect the bounding box coordinates of the red content in order to save it to the database. Basically the points to calculate this:

[image]

Right now I'm able to do this but by looping every single pixel which is quite a heavy procedure. Any idea on a better logic for this?

Comment: Max number of red dots? Do you have to have a bounding rectangle or can it be a polygon? Expected output format?

Comment: `looping every single pixel which is quite a heavy procedure` I'm pretty sure you have to loop through each pixel at least once. So i'm not sure you're going to get much better than O(n).

Comment: Lastly, this site is for code that doesn't work. For optimization and etc. on WORKING code you should post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/